# Selection aware keyBindingFn in draftjs

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I'm experimenting with Draft.js, and I'm trying to emulate a little bit of markdown keybindings.

My thought is that if the cursor is at the start of a line (and there is no selection), I'd like the `#` key to increase the header level.

Now, I have code that works for this, but it seems a bit fragile.  The keyBindingFn(e) doesn't have access to the editor state, so I can only check if `e.key === '#'`, and return `'increase-header-level'`.  Then, in the `handleKeyCommand`, I can check the state to see if the user is at the beginning of the line. The unfortunate thing is that if they aren't, I have to manually update the content to add a `#` character.

It would make sense to me to make the `keyBindingFn` check the state, but I'm not sure if it would be safe to access the `EditorState` there, since it isn't being passed in.

```
    keyBindingFunction(e) {
        if (e.key === '#') {
            console.log('increase-header-level')
            return 'increase-header-level'
        }
        let defaultKeyBinding = Draft.getDefaultKeyBinding(e)
        console.log(defaultKeyBinding)
        return defaultKeyBinding

    }

    handleKeyCommand(command, editorState) {
        if (command === 'increase-header-level') {
            let selection = editorState.getSelection()
            if (selection.getStartKey() === selection.getEndKey()) {
                if (selection.getStartOffset() === 0) {
                    this.increaseHeaderLevel(editorState, selection);
                    return false
                }
            }
            const contentState = Draft.Modifier.replaceText(editorState.getCurrentContent(), editorState.getSelection(), "#")
            this.onChange(EditorState.push(editorState, contentState, 'insert-characters'))
            return true
        }
        let newState = RichUtils.handleKeyCommand(editorState, command)
        if (newState) {
            this.onChange(newState)
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="rich-editor-container">
                <Editor
                    editorState={this.state.editorState}
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                    handleKeyCommand={this.handleKeyCommand}
                    keyBindingFn={this.keyBindingFunction}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out the way to do it:

```
    render() {
        let keyBindFunction;
        if (this.state.editorState.getSelection().getStartOffset() === 0) {
            keyBindFunction = (e) => { return e.key === '#' ? 'increase-header-level' : Draft.getDefaultKeyBinding(e)}
        }
        return (
            <div className="rich-editor-container">
                <Editor
                    editorState={this.state.editorState}
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                    handleKeyCommand={this.handleKeyCommand}
                    keyBindingFn={keyBindFunction}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
```

I'll clean it up with an `isAtStartOfBlock` function, and a mapping for key commands at the start of block, but this is good enough for a PoC.

If this could lead to some unexpected race condition, please let me know.  I don't want to have to hunt down strange failures in the future ;-)